# How do I load my test yaml file prior to running my Django test?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, unit-testing, fixtures

I'm using Django and Python 3.7.  I would like some test data loaded before running my tests.  I thought specifying a "fixtures" element in my test would do this, but it doesn't seem to be loaded.  I created the file, mainpage/fixtures/test_data.yaml, with this content

```
model: mainpage.website
  pk: 1
  fields:
    path: /testsite

model: mainpage.article
  pk: 1
  fields:
    website: 1
    title: 'mytitle'
    path: '/test-path'
    url: 'http://www.mdxomein.com/path'
    created_on:
      type: datetime
      columnDefinition: TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

model: mainpage.articlestat:
  pk: 1
  fields:
    article: 1
    elapsed_time_in_seconds: 300
    hits: 2
```

I specify the fixture in my test file below ...

```
from django.test import TestCase
from mainpage.models import ArticleStat, Article
import unittest


class TestModels(unittest.TestCase):

    fixtures = ['/mainpage/fixtures/test_data.yaml',]

    # Test saving an article stat that hasn't previously
    # existed
    def test_add_articlestat(self):
        id = 1
        article = Article.objects.filter(id=id)
        self.assertTrue(article, "A pre-condition of this test is that an article exist with id=" + str(id))
        articlestat = ArticleStat(article=article,elapsed_time_in_seconds=250,votes=25,comments=15)
        articlestat.save()
        article_stat = ArticleStat.objects.get(article=article)
        self.assertTrue(article_stat, "Failed to svae article stat properly.")
```

But it doesn't appear any of the test data is loaded when my test is run ...

```
(venv) localhost:mainpage_project davea$ cd /Users/davea/Documents/workspace/mainpage_project; source ./venv/bin/activate; python manage.py test
test activated!
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/mainpage_project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py:1421: RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField Article.front_page_first_appeared_date received a naive datetime (2019-01-30 17:02:31.329751) while time zone support is active.
  RuntimeWarning)
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
F
======================================================================
FAIL: test_add_articlestat (mainpage.tests.TestModels)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/mainpage_project/mainpage/tests.py", line 15, in test_add_articlestat
    self.assertTrue(article, "A pre-condition of this test is that an article exist with id=" + str(id))
AssertionError: <QuerySet []> is not true : A pre-condition of this test is that an article exist with id=1

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.001s
```

I've tried changing the file name to something that doesn't exist at all to see if I get a different error but I don't.  So I don't think this "Fixtures" convention is working at all.  How do I get my test data loaded prior to running my test?

Comment: I'm not convinced that this is the problem, as you should get an exception for a missing fixture, but can you try changing it to `fixtures = ['test_data.yaml']`? Django should be auto-prefixing it to use a `fixtures` directory in the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use fixtures that way, `TransactionTestCase.fixtures` needs to be set.
<sup>[1](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.TransactionTestCase.fixtures)</sup>

The magic to load fixtures happens in `TransactionTestCase`. This is makes it so that Test classes that subclasses `TransactionTestCase` e.g. `django.test.TestCase` also load up fixtures specified in the fixtures attribute.
<sup>[2](https://github.com/django/django/blob/2.1.5/django/test/testcases.py#L973)</sup>

The current `TestModels` test class subclasses `unitest.TestCase` and therefore does nothing with the fixtures setup. <sup>[3](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/testing/tools/#fixture-loading)</sup>

```
from django.test import TestCase

class TestModels(TestCase):
    fixtures = ['test_data.yaml',]
```

Usually it is just fine to set the name for the fixture file and not the entire path to the fixture file.
If you need to set a custom folder for fixtures to be discovered in, that can be specified by setting `FIXTURE_DIRS` <sup>[4](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/django-admin/#what-s-a-fixture)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You should (as @OluwafemiSule) states in his answer using `django.test.TestCase` in order to the class attribute `fixtures` is taken into account.

### Could you implement your test and load fixtures using `unittest.TestCase`?

Though is not recommended you could load your fixtures programmatically in your `setUp` method like this:

```
from django.core.management import call_command

def setUp(self): 
   call_command('loaddata', 'initial_data.yml', app_label='myapp')
```

but this approach will require you rollback any change you make to the loaded data if you what to use it in the subsequent tests.

### The right way

From The Django testing docs in the section [Fixtures in Unit Tests](https://django-testing-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fixtures.html#fixtures-in-unit-tests) you can read:

> The big thing that the Django Testcase does for you in regards to fixtures is that **it maintains a consistent state for all of your tests. Before each test is run, the database is flushed: returning it to a pristine state** (like after your first syncdb). Then your fixture gets loaded into the DB, then setUp() is called, then your test is run, then tearDown() is called. **Keeping your tests insulated from each other is incredibly important when you are trying to make a good test suite**.

That's why you should be using `django.test.TestCase`.

### Are your fixtures good?

Another important tip is that you can use the command [testserver](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#testserver-fixture-fixture) to see if your fixtures are good:

```
$ django-admin testserver mydata.json
```

this will runs a Django development server (as in runserver) using data from the given fixture(s). You can read about [testserver](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#testserver-fixture-fixture) command and you'll find out that's a very useful tool.